# discriminated union with literals

Tags: types, f#, literals

What is the correct syntax in F# for a bit type, only two possible values: 0 and 1. 
I have tried;

```
type bit = 
         | 0
         | 1
```

and the error message is `error FS0010: Unexpected integer literal in union case`.
Do I need to use  `[<Literal>]`?

I received a different error message: `error FS0010: Unexpected integer literal in union case. Expected identifier, '(', '(*)' or other token.`

Comment: `[<Literal>]` is an interesting attribute, but it is for `let`'s, not for DU's. Google it.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for a type-safe representation of `Bit`, you may prefer DUs to enums for exhaustive pattern matching:

```
type Bit = Zero | One
with member x.Value =
     match x with
     | Zero -> 0
     | One -> 1
```

If you would like to have a compact representation, `boolean` type is a good candidate:

```
let [<Literal>] Zero = false
let [<Literal>] One = true

let check = function
    | Zero -> "It's Zero"
    | One -> "It's One"
```

When there is a collection of `Bit`s, you could look into [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) for more efficient treatment. They indeed use `boolean` as the internal representation.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use an enum -

```
type bit = 
     | Zero= 0
     | One = 1
```

Although the pattern matching is not quite as good as for discriminated unions.

Alternatively you can use a DU with

```
type bit =
|Zero
|One
member x.Int() =
    match x with
    |Zero -> 0
    |One -> 1
```